# Storing key value where key repeats and using primary keys

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I am in a situation where i have to store `key -> value` pairs in a table which signifies users who have voted certain products.

```
UserId    ProductID
1         2345
1         1786
6         657
2         1254
1         2187
```

As you can see that `userId` keeps on repeating and so can `productId`. I wanted to know what can be the best way to represent this data. Also is there a necessity of using primary key in here. I've searched a lot but am not able to find the exact specification about my problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can a user vote for the same product more than once?

Comment: Many users can vote for same product.

Comment: That's not what I asked: Can a given user vote multiple times for a given product?

Comment: No he can not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enforce that a given user can vote for a given product at most once, create a unique constraint over both columns:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (UserId, ProductID);
```

Although you can use these two columns together as a key, your app code is often simpler if you define a separate, typically auto increment, key column, but the decision to do this depends on which app code language/library you use.

If you have any tables that hold a foreign key reference to this table, and you intend to use referential integrity, those tables and the SQL used to define the relationship will also be simpler if you create a separate key column - you just end up carting multiple columns around instead of just one.

Comment: This is exactly what i was thinking of doing in first place. Thank you!